# Django created_at__gt=self.request.user.last_login workinly only on users already signed in.

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

**Intro:** I have a 3 models `user`, `post`, `group`. User is able to make posts however each post has to belong to a group. Users have to choose from the existing groups for their posts. Users cannot add, delete, update group's.

Furthermore:

Users can become a member of groups and when they click on a certain group. They see all the posts in that group.

**What I want** When Users come on the home page they see posts that were added since the last time they logged in

[image]

**My Models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**My Views**

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['object_list'] = Group.objects.filter(members=self.request.user)

            #What am I doing wrong in the below code
            new_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__gt=self.request.user.last_login).count()
            context['new_posts'] = new_posts
         else:
              context['object_list'] = Group.objects.all()
        return context
```

In my templates I have

```
<div class="list-group">
   {% for group in object_list %}        
       {% if not new_posts %}
               {{group.post.count}}
        {% else %}
                {{new_posts}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

> **The Issue:** Only the users who are already signed in and refresh their page see the new posts *example:`4 new`, `3new` etc..*. If a user signs in fresh after a new posts are created in a group. He does not see the `4 new`, `3new` . Instead it shows him just the number of posts in the group. not the new posts since he logged in. Why is this happening?

Comment: First, tell me?
1. Are you storing the user session? 
2. Are you auto logging out the user? 
What do you want... something like social media e.i Instagram, facebook timeline where you get all the posts from the last time you logged in? Then you can use something like `getstream.io` coupled with signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its normal behavior because `last_login` stores datetime at which the user last logged in. When the user fresh logs in into the system, it stores the current time (timezone.now). So if a post is created before he is logged in, then it will not appear into the `new_posts`. So if you want to store the previous login/logout time, then you need to store it somewhere else(or make a new model field). You can try like this using [user logged out signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals):

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out


def do_stuff(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    user.logout_time = timezone.now()
    user.save()

user_logged_out.connect(do_stuff)  # Hook an a method to user_logged_out signal to update logout time
```

And use it in the View like this:

```
last_post = Post.objects.last()
if last_post.created_at < request.user.last_login:
   new_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__gt=self.request.user.logout_time).count()
   context['new_posts'] = new_posts
```

### Update

In this example, it is required to have a field to store logout time. If you have a **CustomUser** then you can directly create it in the CustomUser Model. Else, you can add it like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    logout_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

and store logout time like this:

```
user.profile.logout_time = timezone.now()
```

and filter New Posts Like this:

```
new_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__gt=self.request.user.profile.logout_time)
```

Comment: Sorry just realized where are we using `user_logged_out` in the second part of the code

Comment: Getting this error `'User' object has no attribute 'logout_time'`

Comment: @SamirTendulkar please see the update section of the answer