# Is there a way to get the time of users last logout time Django example user.last_logout (does anything like this exist)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-users

**Intro:** I have a 3 models `user`, `post`, `group`. User is able to make posts however each post has to belong to a group. Users have to choose from the existing groups for their posts. Users cannot add, delete, update group's.

Furthermore:

Users can become a member of groups and when they click on a certain group. They see all the posts in that group.

**What I want** When Users come on the home page they see posts that were added since the last time they logged in

[image]

**My Models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**My Views**

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['object_list'] = Group.objects.filter(members=self.request.user)

            #The last login actually shows the users current login time as the last login. Which makes the below line of code useless
            new_posts = Post.objects.filter(created_at__gt=self.request.user.last_login).count()
            context['new_posts'] = new_posts
         else:
              context['object_list'] = Group.objects.all()
        return context
```

In my templates I have

```
<div class="list-group">
   {% for group in object_list %}        
       {% if not new_posts %}
               {{group.post.count}}
        {% else %}
                {{new_posts}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

> **The Issue:** The last login actually shows the users current login time as the last login. Is there a way to get users last logout time instead of last login time example user.last_logout

I have the below answer but it doesn't seem to work for me
[Django created_at__gt=self.request.user.last_login workinly only on users already signed in.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805056/django-created-at-gt-self-request-user-last-login-workinly-only-on-users-alread/53805298#53805298)

> My profile create function

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return redirect('accounts:edit_profile')
```

Comment: You could have a field that records the *last_logout*, deal whit it in a custom logout view where you will save the *current time* logged out

Comment: @Lemayzeur Could you show it in code

Answer (score 1):

here is an example

```
 class ProfileModel(models.Model):
     #fields
     last_time_logout = models.DateTimeField()
```

In a custom view, record the last logout

```
 import datetime

 def signout(request):
     profile = reques.user.profile # it depends 
     if request.is_ajax(): # Do it with ajax
          logout(request)
          profile.last_time_logout = datetime.datetime.now()
          profile.save()
          return redirect("signin")
     raise PermissionDenied
```

Comment: do you think it should be 

`def signout(request):`
      ''' logout user '''
      `request.user.profile.last_time_logout = datetime.datetime.now()`
      `request.user.profile.save()`

Comment: Also will this always record the users logout time. Is `def signout` a django function

Comment: I name it that way to avoid confusion with the built-in function `logout` of Django. If you use that view to end the session, yes it will always record the last time log out

Comment: ok if I want to use it with the built in log out function how will the code look like. Example is it `def logout` or `def signout`

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. but it did not work for me. Maybe I am doing something wrong, This solution worked for me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837536/how-to-save-the-users-last-logout-time.