# How to save the users last logout time

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I am looking to save the users last logout time.My idea was to add it to the users profile model. I am using Django 1.11.15

Example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    ...
    last_logout = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

below is how I created my profile model just for reference

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return redirect('accounts:edit_profile')
    else:
        form = UserCreateForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context)
```

Below is what I intend to do. Is this the correct way. I want to add to django's default signout/logout method I am not sure if its called `signout` or `logout`

```
class LoggedOut(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'logged_out.html'
    def signout(self):
        """logout user """
        self.request.user.profile.last_logout = datetime.now()
        self.request.user.profile.save()
```

My URL's

```
url(r'^loggedout/$', views.LoggedOut.as_view(), name='loggedout'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Django [logout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out) signal for such purpose.

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def sig_user_logged_out(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
     user.profile.last_logout = datetime.now()
     user.profile.save()
```

Comment: trying this now

Comment: awesome dude I almost underestimated you because of your reputation it worked. Just made a few tweaks

`@receiver(user_logged_out)`
`def sig_user_logged_out(sender, user, request, **kwargs):`
    `request.user.profile.last_logout = datetime.datetime.now()`
    `request.user.profile.save()`

Comment: @SamirTendulkar `(Pdb) user
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: 8567075678>>
(Pdb) user.email
''
(Pdb) user.email = "iamjagjeetubhi@gmail.com"
(Pdb) user.save()
(Pdb) user
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: 8567075678>>
(Pdb) user.email
'iamjagjeetubhi@gmail.com'
(Pdb) request.user
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: 8567075678>>`
Have a look both user and request.user are same.